# Llamar una funcion

Tags: c

cree el Int DigitNum y quisiera llamarlo dentro del Main en el While

```
int DigitNum(int mat[], int a,int b) --- Funcion

while(DigitNum == 1); 
    {
        printf("\nDigite un numero de %i cifras: ", a);
        scanf("%i",&b);
        DigitNum(mat,a,b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pretendes hacer se hace así, lo primero en la definición de la función ha de terminar en punto y coma:

```
int DigitNum(int mat[], int a, int b);
```

Luego en la función main haríamos un bucle con la condición al final, de esta forma:

```
int main()
{
       
   do
   {
       printf("\nDigite un numero de %i cifras: ", a);
       scanf("%i",&b);
   } while(DigitNum(mat,a,b) == 1);

   return 0;
}
```